# Sequent calculus proofs using the prooftree package

Tags: proof-package, bussproofs

I am finding it difficult writing sequent calculus proofs using `\usepackage{prooftree}` and cannot find any sufficiently detailed resources on this matter. Can anyone give me a link to such resources? I found this, http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/proofs/taylor/prooftree-doc.pdf, but it is not detailed enough for me.

Comment: Have you already explored the options mentioned in  [`LaTeX for logicians`](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/)?

Comment: Yes. I have to use prooftree, and the information there is not detailed enough for that package.

Comment: Why do you *have* to use `prooftree`? According to the site, `bussproofs` is "The best, most flexible package" and it has an user giude.

Comment: I don't have to strictly speaking. I have some proofs in the proof tree package that I want to preserve, but since, say, Buss's package uses \begin{prooftree} and \end{prooftree}, if I have both buss's package and the proof tree package side by side in the same document it crashes. There may be a way out of this, but it sounds ever so complicated!

Comment: I've tried to use this ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/prftree/prftreedoc.pdf, but it doesn't seem to recognise a proof such as \begin{displaymath}
\prftree[r]{$\supset$I}
{\prftree[r]{$\supset$I}
{\prftree[r]{$\supset$E}
{\prfboundedassumption{A}}
{\prfboundedassumption{\neg A}}
{\bot}}
{\neg\neg A}}
{A \supset \neg\neg A}
\end{displaymath}

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `ebproofs` (or `ebproof`?) is a more recent alternative, similar to `bussproofs`, I think.

Comment: You can always compile them standalone and then include them as external images.